# Does Flashing Stock ROM in Odin Clear out the System Partition First?

Tags: system, odin

Does Flashing Stock Samsung ROM in Odin Clear out the System Partition First?

Options Used:
No repartition,
ROM put inside PDA slot

I'm wondering because I suspect there may have been some malware in the previous ROM that was flashed.  So I want to be sure all the Files that were in the System Partition Previously are deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Odin then I am asuming you have a samsung device. 
Depending on what Stock rom you use, I mean if you will flash using 1 file or 3 file rom, if you have a 3 file rom then you have to put in the pit file to, and then you can enable the re-partition.

If you use 1 file rom in odin, i think it will re-partition by default so you do not have to check the repartition check box in odin.

Comment: This doesn't address that question of whether Odin flashing Stock OFficial ROMs will clear out everything preexisting on the System Partition instead of merely overwriting existing files and leaving others untouched.

Comment: If you repartition, you delete everything.

Comment: I dont' have a 3 file ROM, so would the only way to clear System Partition be thru CWM and select Format System partition?

Comment: If you have a 1 file ROM, I THINK it will automaticaly repartition, but I am not sure. Using the CWM to format the System partition...I don't know exactly.